# Having problems with booting GRUB for EFI on USB stick

Tags: linux, macos, mac, grub, uefi

Whatever I do, it constantly drops me into the 'bash prompt'. Never displays a menu, nothing. I'm running GRUB on a USB stick formatted as msdos (so, FAT) and when I boot into it, GRUB simply won't load its grub.cfg file, even though I'm sure the right modules are included.

This is what I did:

**Compiling GRUB**

```
./configure --with-platform=efi --enable-grub-fstest=no  --enable-grub-mkfont=no --disable-nls --enable-efiemu=no
```

**Making Image**

```
../grub-mkimage -d . -O x86_64-efi -p . -o ~/Desktop/bootx64.efi boot linux ext2 normal configfile lspci ls reboot datetime loadenv search lvm help hfsplus hfs echo fat exfat multiboot multiboot2 terminal
```

And, finally, here's my grub.cfg file:

```
timeout=10
default=0
set color_normal=yellow/blue
set color_highlight=blue/yellow

menuentry "Fedora 12" {
    root=(hd0,2)
    linux /vmlinuz-2.6.32.9-70.fc12.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_ultra-lv_root LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rhgb quiet nolapic
    initrd /initramfs-2.6.32.9-70.fc12.x86_64.img
}

menuentry "Boot OS X" {
    insmod hfsplus
    set root=(hd0,X) #change X to the Mac SL partition
    multiboot /boot
}

menuentry "Reboot" {
    reboot
}
```

The grub.cfg file is located in the same folder as grub.efi. Not sure why GRUB won't read its config.

Comment: I'm using GRUB 2.0 rc1.

Comment: Not sure about grub because i use Refined bootloader for EFI/UEFI booting.. Have you tried a Usb EFI shell? you can boot the vmlinuz from the shell - you could take a look at my guide to installing arch linux on efi since it should be similar http://pcavdisor.blogspot.ca

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I'm trying to do. I'm an application developer, and I'm making a tool to boot a Linux ISO from a USB drive... The ultimate goal is to have GRUB boot from the USB, boot an ISO I've stored there, and pass control off seamlessly. I've considered embedding the grub.cfg into GRUB, but I want to wait on that until I know it works. I guess that will be the next thing to try though.

Comment: this can be done with a EFI shell usb stick.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like it to be automatic or with as little user intervention as possible. Having to type into an EFI she'll doesn't fulfill that requirement.

Comment: That's true - i guess you'll have to program up what you need :P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8251/discussion-between-sevenbits-and-dashboard)